# PostgreSQL server process -> client process mapping

Tags: postgresql

How can I find which client process is connected to a server process?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_stat_activity
```

More details in the manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/monitoring.html

Comment: For most of my server processes client_addr is NULL and client_port is -1. Probably because I'm using UNIX sockets to connect. Is there any way to find the client in that way?